# Repeated opening hours using txt file

Tags: javascript

Here's this well-established timed shutdown. Would it be possible to get the value between var onlineweekdays = {} from e.g. a .txt file? That is, the opening time would not be set in this scirpt, but in another file. This would be necessary so that my staff doesn't have to fiddle with the code. But it could also be a solution to take the data from an Outlook (M365) calendar for example. Is this possible, can any of these variants be solved?

```
<script>
 var a = document.getElementById("online");
var d = new Date();
var n = d.getDay();
var now = d.getHours() + "." + d.getMinutes();
var onlineweekdays = {
    0: null, //Vasárnap
    1: [6.30, 16.30], //hétfő
    2: [6.30, 16.30], //kedd
    3: [6.30, 16.30], //szerda
    4: [6.30, 16.30], //csütörtök
    5: [6.30, 15.30], //péntek
    6: null //Szombat
};
var onlinedayWorkingHours = onlineweekdays[n]; //Today working hours. if null we are close

if (onlinedayWorkingHours && (now > onlinedayWorkingHours[0] && now < onlinedayWorkingHours[1])) {
  // check if current time is during or beyond 15 minutes before closing time
if (isFifteenMinBeforeOut2(now, onlinedayWorkingHours[1])) {
    a.innerHTML = "rövidesen zárunk."; 
       a.style.backgroundColor = '#fee599'; 
       a.style.color = '#7f6000';
       a.style.textTransform = 'uppercase';
       a.style.fontWeight = 'bold';
       a.style.padding = '0 4px';
       a.style.borderRadius = '3px';
       a.style.marginLeft ='5px';
  } 
  else {
    a.innerHTML = "most elérhető."; 
       a.style.backgroundColor = '#e2efd9'; 
       a.style.color = '#538135';
       a.style.textTransform = 'uppercase';
       a.style.fontWeight = 'bold';
       a.style.padding = '0 4px';
       a.style.borderRadius = '3px';
       a.style.marginLeft ='5px';
  } 
  } else {
     a.innerHTML = "most nem érhető el.";
       a.style.backgroundColor = '#efd9df'; 
       a.style.color = '#c91f41';
       a.style.textTransform = 'uppercase';
       a.style.fontWeight = 'bold';
       a.style.padding = '0 4px';
       a.style.borderRadius = '3px';
       a.style.marginLeft ='5px';
}

function isFifteenMinBeforeOut2(current, clockout) {
    return current >= clockout - 0.10;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The data can't be accessed from a file on the client side, as filesystem access is restricted from browser.

To be able to get a dynamic list of values you will have to either

- configure your own backend to host the data(or to fetch from outlook).
- host the configuration somewhere like [Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/), and fetch it through a network request

if the data does not contain sensitive details, and you dont want to set up a backend, you can opt for the 2nd method.